# Flowplayer6 does not work on mobile

Tags: wordpress, html, video, mobile, flowplayer

I'm using Flowplayer6 / HTML5 wordpress plugin to play videos on the site.
I have trouble playing the player on the phone. By clicking on the player, the video does not run .

Please find an online example of the problem below:
http://www.muzika.com.br/vertice/player_portacurtas/filme/?name=j_carlos_o_cronista_do_rio

obs .: the 5/2 is normal to stop the video.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [know issues section](https://flowplayer.org/docs/known-issues.html) in `flowplayer` documentation, it seems that:

> - Mobile devices and iOS do not support automatic playback on page load.
>     Volume and mute state cannot be controlled on mobile platforms and
>     iOS.
> - Mobile phones and iPod do not allow inline playback in the
>     browser. The native player component takes over entirely. They
>     therefore also do not fully support the JavaScript API, especially
>     when it comes to interaction with the page.

You will find in the documentation some workarounds, but maybe this is not the right plugin for what you need.

Comment: I read this documentation , but it was not enough to answer my question. The problem is not auto load or controls. The player simply does not run the video when you click the play . In another demo page you just created with the same player, worked corretmente . Tanks!